# Dose zookeeper servers must use SSD disks?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, ssd, kafka, zookeeper

we want to install kafka cluster and 3 zookeeper servers

kafka should use the zookeeper servers in order to save the metadata on the zookeeper servers

ZK Data and Log files should be on disks, which have least contention from other I/O activities. Ideally the ZK data and ZK transaction log files should be on different disks, so that they don't contend for the IO resource.

Note that, it isn't enough to just have partitions but they have to be different disks to ensure performance.

So dose zookeeper server must use SSD disks ?

if yes what are the minimum requirements for zoo disks as IO ,etc.

Answer (score 1):

It's not mandatory to use SSD for zookeeper, issue raised when actually too many application using same zookeeper and doing lots of transaction on zookeeper, AFAIK I past with production cluster running HDD without any issue, I/O will be bottleneck if and only transactions are huge(It also depend of application design). Kafka/Hadoop not necessary required ssd for zookeeper.